# Carto CSS variables

Tags: tilemill, mapbox, cartocss

Does anyone know whether it's possible to use a variable within an attribute selector. 
For example I define my variable at the top of the file:

```
@lowZoomMax: 9;
```

And then reference it as follows:

```
#settlement {
 [zoom > @lowZoomMax] {
...
...
}
}
```

This doesn't appear to work in the map I currently have - I get `Invalid Code: @lowZoomMax` (in the second bit of code, not the definition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it should be in the current version: https://github.com/mapbox/carto/issues/197

Could the error be because you included a { before the zoom filter?

Comment: Yeah, it is in Carto, just not in the release version of TileMill - details at https://github.com/mapbox/carto/issues/337